# How to change VSCode File title height?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to change VSCode File title height?

Sorry, I don't know the keyword for this issue. Could you help me?

[image: filenter image description here]

Comment: in NavBar or in Editor Next?

Answer (score 1):

Not available, but under discussion.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42253